# SpringBoot WebMvcConfigurationSupport didn't take configureMessageConverters when we get bean in

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, converters

In `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` child class we override the method `configureMessageConverters`.

When we get one converters like a bean,

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new EventServiceObjectMapper());

    return jacksonConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

the `configuration-loader` didn't take our converters.

But when we declare all in the method, the `configuration-loader` take our converters.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new EventServiceObjectMapper()));
}
```

It's normal? I miss something?

Dependencies ::

> Spring webmvc 4.3.22.RELEASE
>
> SpringBoot 1.5.19.RELEASE

Comment: Please add Error StackTrace...

Comment: Don't extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` instead implement `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Comment: They didn't have error. We the  first code, it's take the default converters. With the second it's take my converters and that I want. So, If I want use a bean to declare a converter can be get by RestTemplate, I cannot use it in method to declare the converters for controller.

Comment: I extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (same then implement WebMvcConfigurer without need to implements all methods) and now is stronger. It's take a group of default converters x 2 and the two I declared for a total of 16. The initial bug I did before change to WebMvcConfigurationSupport. And the result for the both code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution. Extends the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, and implements extendMessageConverters, clear the converters and set only converters I want.

```
@Bean
public HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(){
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new EventServiceObjectMapper());

    return jacksonConverter;
}

@Override
public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.clear();
    converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggle with WebMVC and RestAPI. Once `@EnableWebMvc`, it will override `spring.jackson.*` config.

My solution, get current `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and custom it that I want.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired  // spring.jackson.* ObjectMapper's config
    public WebConfig(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream()
                .filter(x -> x instanceof  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .forEach(x -> ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) x).setObjectMapper(mapper));
    }
}
```